# Merging txt files whose last letters repeat in python

Tags: python

I have a folder that includes txt files. Txt files' names always end up with those years '_1980', '_1981' '_1982' ... '_2015', but their names start with different numbers. I want to merge txt files whose file names start with same letters/numbers but finish with those numbers above.
As an example for the txt files,
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P335f.jpg)

Eventually, merged file are abc_allyears.txt and xyz_allyears.txt and so on 'otherletters'_allyears.txt

Can you write related python code?
Thank you.

Comment: `Can you write related python code`. That's not how this works. This is a programming Q/A site. If you have a programming issue, please post the code you are having issue with so we can help you along. You should only post here as a last resort. For example: After you've debugged, after you've researched and most importantly, after you've tried. Please read over [how to produce a minimal, verifiable, complete example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I understand what I have to do before asking a question. Thank you for your warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, this script assumes that it is being run from the same directory as the files you described in the question (this can be easily modified). It finds all the files that end with four-digits plus `.txt`, groups them together by the starting characters (before `'_'`) and writes the contents of each into a single file with those same starting characters plus `_allyears.txt`.

```
from glob import glob
from itertools import groupby

filenames = sorted(glob('*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt'))

for k, g in groupby(filenames, key=lambda f: f.rsplit('_', 1)[0]):
    with open('{}_allyears.txt'.format(k), 'w') as outfile:
        for filename in g:
            with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: It worked but it merged all files whose names are before '_'. My files name is '32.125_30.125_1980.txt for example. It merged like 32.125_allyears.txt. It supposed to be 32.125_30.125_allyears.txt.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded two pictures. In the images, you can see how merged files. https://ibb.co/hODdno
https://ibb.co/hyW9tT

Comment: @f.yunusemreCevahir Ah, I think it could be a single character fix. The sample filenames you provided only included a single `'_'` character in each filename but this new one you've provided me has two. Changing `f.split` to `f.rsplit` seems to work, I'll edit the answer right now to show you.

Comment: @f.yunusemreCevahir Example: https://bpaste.net/show/305d7506a074

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following code and make sure to chane the directory location in mypath. Hope this helps.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
#make sure to change this to your dir location and dont forget ending 
#backslash 

mypath="Your/Dir/Location/"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

#sorts the files according to the years

#dummy value to rerun the program without worries if necessary
sortedList=sorted(onlyfiles,key=lambda x:int(x.split("_")[1].replace(".txt","")) if not "Years" in x else 10000)
print(sortedList)

import collections
#get a set of filename starters
fileNameSet=collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(f.split("_")[0] for f in sortedList)
print(fileNameSet)

#iterate through the files for files starting with these names
for uniqueName in fileNameSet:
    contentToWrite=""
    for fileNames in sortedList:
        if fileNames.startswith(uniqueName) and "Years" not in fileNames:
            with open(mypath+fileNames,"r") as currFile:
                contentToWrite+=currFile.read()
    with open(mypath+uniqueName+"_allYears.txt","w+") as writeFile:
        writeFile.write(contentToWrite)
```

If this answers your question, please mark as resolved.